# Clear array and text box with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Each time a checkbox is checked, the below function will be called. My problem is that I need another function which should clear all the data available here.

Let me explain my problem first:

The concept of the program is to update the text box with the checkbox value -  if two check boxes are checked, then the text box will have two values in it and so on.

I need a function to clear the data on the check box so that when I click the 3rd check box it needs to show only the 3rd checkbox's value by removing the first and second from the text area. This should all happen without reloading the page

```
<script>
    function chkcontrol(j){
        var textbox = document.getElementById("list");
        var textbox1 = document.getElementById("val_id");
        var values = [];    
        var val_id=[];
        if(document.getElementById(1).checked) {
            values.push('A1');
            val_id.push('1');
        }
        if(document.getElementById(2).checked) {
            values.push('A2');
            val_id.push('2');   }
        if(document.getElementById(3).checked) {
            values.push("A3");
            val_id.push('3');
        }
        if(document.getElementById(4).checked) {
            values.push("A4");
            val_id.push('4');
        }
        if(document.getElementById(5).checked) {
            values.push("A5");
            val_id.push('5');
        }
        if(document.getElementById(6).checked) {
            values.push("A6");
            val_id.push('6');
        }

        textbox.value = values.join(",");
        textbox1.value = val_id.join(",");
    }

    function removeAll(){
    }
</script>

<input id="list" type="text" name="list">
<input id="val_id" type="text" name="val_id">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="A1" id="1" onclick='chkcontrol(0)';>
<label for="1"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="A2" id="2" onclick='chkcontrol(0)';>
<label for="2"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="A3" id="3" onclick='chkcontrol(0)';>
<label for="3"></label>
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in here Oo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you need here, but if you need to "clear" an javascript array just set length to 0 (zero).

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
a.length = 0; // truncate array
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length#Description) says:
"You can set the length property to truncate an array at any time."

Hope it helps you...

Comment: Let me give you some screen shots so that you can catch my problem

Answer (score 0):

To save yourself some typing (and have less chance of error) the elements should be accessed using a loop, e.g.

```
for (var i=1; i<7; i++) {

  if (document.getElementById(i).checked) {
    values.push('A' + i);
    val_id.push('' + 1);
  }
}
```

If the elements are in a form, consider accessing them as named properties of the form rather than calling *getElementById* multiple times:

```
var form = document.getElementById(formID);
...
```

However, for that you will need to assign a name that isn't a number to avoid clashes with the index of the control, so if you rename them to say "input_1" etc. then you can do:

```
  if (form['input_' + i].checked) {
```

To set the value of a "textbox" (I'll guess that's either an input type text or textarea element) to its default:

```
textbox.value = textbox.defaultValue;
textbox1.value = textbox1.defaultValue;
```

To "clear" an array, either set its length to 0:

```
values.length = 0;
```

or just replace it with a new array

```
values = [];
```

If the array is referenced by multiple variables, do the first; otherwise either will do.

Comment: Look at the fallowing example i need the same kind of code with an additional feature..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I just spent 29 minutes on your code, but here it is anyway. Enjoy. A couple of pointers for the future:

1. Try and keep your script away from your markup i.e. no onclick events if you're going to use jQuery.
2. If you find yourself doing endless if statements over collections of DOM elements, there is probably a better way.

Anyway, I'll get off my high horse, here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type=\"checkbox\"][name=\"ckb\"]").click(function () {
                var values = [];
                var val_id = [];
                var checked = $("input[type=\"checkbox\"][name=\"ckb\"]:checked");
                if (checked.length < 3) {
                    checked.each(function (i, e) {
                        values.push($(e).val());
                        val_id.push($(e).prop("id"));
                    });
                } else {
                    values.push($(this).val());
                    val_id.push($(this).prop("id"));
                }
                $("input#list").val(values.join(","));
                $("input#val_id").val(val_id.join(","));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="list" type="text" name="list">
    <input id="val_id" type="text" name="val_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="A1" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="A2" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="A3" id="3">
</body>
</html>
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/df59H/

And if you need to clear the boxes:

```
$("#someButtonId").click(function(){
    $("input#list").val("");
    $("input#val_id").val("");
});
```

Comment: YES this is what i need but with a little more features.. I have 300 more checkboxes and i man select any of them..
I need that feature in the fallowing way..
First I need a button included in this page next if i select 3 checkboxes and click on the button it will do some action which i need.. Lateron when i click on the 4th check box it need to show me only the 4th one and so on.. So i need to clear that when i click on the button is that possible

Comment: As long as they are named ckb, you can add as many as you need, it will adapt. Glad to help.

Comment: With rudimentary changes i.e < 3 to < 4, you should be able to adapt my script to whatever you need as per your edited comment.

Comment: I understood the logic but when i click on the button the array need to be cleared so that i can select other checkboxes. How to clear both the arrays

Comment: The arrays only exist during the click event, they don't need to be cleared. You need to clear the textboxes though when you're done, and the code for that is above...

Comment: What you said is correct sir, But the problem is when i click the button the action is performed on other tab. So this page won't get refreshed. Let me tell you an example i have 10 check boxes with names a1,a2,a3,a4..... so on. coming to the usage when i select a1 and a2 and click on the button action takes place lets forget about the action. Now i like to select a3,a4 but as the a1 and a2 are already in the array even though i cleared the textbox it shows a1,a2,a3,a4 but im expecting only a3,a4 should be on the check box did you get my point

Comment: I'm afraid it's about as clear as mud. You need to start a new question on your new issue, it sounds like something entirely different to your original problem.